# Unable to send data from Zeromq client to TCP server

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, tcp, zeromq

I'm trying to use a zeromq socket as a raw TCP client socket in C++.
I have a TCP server in a different program which I would like to send data to.
When I connect my Zeromq client to the server, I am able to receive data from the server but unable to send data to the TCP server.
When sending I get the following error: Unhandled error, zmq::error_t
Have any idea how to make it work?

```
zmq::context_t *ctx = new zmq::context(100, 100);
void *raw_socket = new zmq::socket_t(*ctx, ZMQ_STREAM);
zmq::socket_t *socket = static_cast<zmq::socket_t*>(raw_socket);

socket->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5555");

char message[] = "HELLO, WORLD!"
socket->send(message, strlen(message), ZMQ_SNDMORE)
```

Comment: What is the need for `raw_socket`?

Comment: The TCP server which I connect to is a TCP server built using python, so I can't use the ZMTP protocol to connect to it.

Comment: But in the example it's completely useless

Comment: What do you meen?

Comment: You assign a pointer to `zmq::socket_t` to a `void*`. Then, the only thing you do with it is to cast it back to `zmq::socket_t*`. That is completely useless. You would achieve the same (plus save some memory) by simply doing `zmq::socket_t *socket = new zmq::socket_t(*ctx, ZMQ_STREAM);`. I see no point in having a `raw_socket` at all.

Comment: Fixed.
But it still doesn't send data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you send or receive anything on a `ZMQ_STREAM` type socket the first data frame should be an identifier that indicates where the subsequent frames should go or where they came from.

When using the `ZMQ_STREAM` socket as a server (i.e you call `bind` on the socket) then you can just extract this identity frame with `recv` and resend it when you respond.

When used as a client (i.e you call `connect` on the socket) then you need to obtain the identity from the socket, you can do this via `getsockopt` with the `ZMQ_IDENTITY` flag.

The identity size is limited to a maximum of 255 bytes.

```
// get the id after you've called connect
std::size_t id_size = 256;
char id[ 256 ];
socket->getsockopt( ZMQ_IDENTITY, &id, &id_size );

// send the id frame
socket->send(id, id_size, ZMQ_SNDMORE);

// then your data
char message[] = "HELLO, WORLD!";
socket->send(message, strlen(message), ZMQ_SNDMORE);
```

The documentation on ZMQ_STREAM goes into more detail about how you'll be notified and control connections, disconnections etc.